# JQuery .tabs - How do I remove tabular navigation from HTML output?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm using the Post UI Tabs module on a website that I'm developing, and so far it does exactly what I need -http://fleshandbuns.virtualabode.com/menus/drinks/

I have one small element of customisation that I'm struggling with and am hoping that someone could kindly point me in the right direction. In brief:

- I need to hide the tabular navigation so that the user only has next/prev buttons - which I've successfully done using CSS
- the challenge I have is preventing the UL (class .ui-tabs-nav) and it's LIs for the tabs from flashing at the top of the main content area during page load. Screenshot example - http://fleshandbuns.virtualabode.com/wp-content/uploads/post-ui-tabs-query.png

So far I've tried

- using CSS to set the LI list-style to none and the A color to #fff, but the UL still flash up on the page
- I've also tried using JQuery .hide, but the UL still flash up on the page

Kind regards
Luke

Answer (score 0):

Use inline `display:none` like this:

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav" style="display:none">
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately that doesn't fix it.